# Editing a playlist configuration file

Tags: bash

What I'm trying to do here is first set the first eight variables to the proper default values. That's the first area I'm thinking there might be a way to optimize. Is there anyway to set both variables at once for example I know in PHP I could do `$title=$d_title="value";` Is there any way to consolidate that section? (The variables prefixed with `d_` will not change, but the same variable without the `d_` may be changed.)

Then the rest of the snippet should do the following:

- If the second argument is NOT "config"

  - Look in the file to see if the a line with the format `${sfile}_variablename="*"` exists.

    - If it does, use sed to replace the contents of the quotes with the new variable
    - If it does not, append the line in its entirety
- If the second argument IS "config"

  - If a line exists that contains `${sfile}_variablename`, read in what's between the quotes and assign it to the variablename
  - If not, set the variablename to the default value

Below is how I was achieving that. Is there any way to do this in a more simplified or compact manner?

In this case, `sdir` is a base path I define elsewhere, and `sfile` is another prefix. Those are hard-coded into the top of the script, so those will always be correct.

```
d_finddir=${2:-"${sdir}/music/trine_soundtrack/"}
finddir=${d_finddir}

d_title=${3:-"Random Tangent"}
title=${d_title}

d_desc=${4:-"Random Tangent Playlist"}
desc=${d_desc}

d_rand=${5:-"randomize"}
rand=${d_rand}


if [ ! "${finddir}" = "config" ]; then
    if egrep -q "${sfile}_finddir" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        sed -r -i "s,(${sfile}_finddir=).*,\\1\"${finddir}\"," "${sdir}/config.cfg"
    else
        printf "%s_finddir=\"%s\"\n" "${sfile}" "${finddir}" >>"${sdir}/config.cfg"
    fi

    if egrep -q "${sfile}_title" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        sed -r -i "s,(${sfile}_title=).*,\\1\"${title}\"," "${sdir}/config.cfg"
    else
        printf "%s_title=\"%s\"\n" "${sfile}" "${title}" >>"${sdir}/config.cfg"
    fi

    if egrep -q "${sfile}_desc" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        sed -r -i "s,(${sfile}_desc=).*,\\1\"${desc}\"," "${sdir}/config.cfg"
    else
        echo "${sfile}_desc=\"${desc}\"">>"${sdir}/config.cfg"
        printf "%s_desc=\"%s\"\n" "${sfile}" "${desc}" >>"${sdir}/config.cfg"
    fi

    if egrep -q "${sfile}_mode" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        sed -r -i "s,(${sfile}_mode=).*,\\1\"${rand}\"," "${sdir}/config.cfg"
    else
        printf "%s_mode=\"%s\"" "${sfile}" "${rand}" >>"${sdir}/config.cfg"
    fi
else
    if egrep -q "${sfile}_finddir" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        finddir=$(egrep "${sfile}_finddir" "${sdir}/config.cfg" | egrep -o "\".+\"" | sed 's/\"//g')
    else
        finddir=${d_finddir}
    fi

    if egrep -q "${sfile}_title" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        title=$(egrep "${sfile}_title" "${sdir}/config.cfg" | egrep -o "\".+\"" | sed 's/\"//g')
    else
        title=${d_title}
    fi

    if egrep -q "${sfile}_desc" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        desc=$(egrep "${sfile}_desc" "${sdir}/config.cfg" | egrep -o "\".+\"" | sed 's/\"//g')
    else
        desc=${d_desc}
    fi

    if egrep -q "${sfile}_mode" "${sdir}/config.cfg"; then
        rand=$(egrep "${sfile}_mode" "${sdir}/config.cfg" | egrep -o "\".+\"" | sed 's/\"//g')
    else
        rand=${d_rand}
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Using sed to its fullest**

  `sed` is surprisingly powerful tool. For example:

  ```
  finddir=$(sed -n -E /"${sfile}_finddir"'/s/[^"]*\"([^"]*).*/\1/p' "${sdir}/config.cfg")
  [ -z ${finddir} ] && finddir=${d_finddir}
  ```

  achieves the desired effect without any `egrep`.

  - **Explanation**: The last line (`[ -z ]`) tests whether `finddir` has zero length (meaning that `sed` didn't find the line in interest) and if so (`&&`) assigns it a default value.
- **Editing the config file**

  I am not sure I understand the decision to edit the config file via the script. It is much more natural (at least within the context provided) to edit it manually.

Comment: I'll look more at that sed example and what it does tonight, but as for the config file, this is part of a longer start script for a program which if not called with config, expects that you're defining the values to start the program.  The config is more of a "This is what you used last time".

Comment: @Trel see the edit

Comment: If I'm reading the `sed` example, and if I'm understanding it right, I'd want to use this format over your example, unless I'm misunderstanding something `sed -n -E "s/${sfile}_finddir=\"([^\"]*).*\".*/\1/p" "${sdir}/config.cfg"` would be what I want to use if I'm going to use -z for the test?

Comment: @Trel You may do that, but why run `sed` twice? It is much easier to save the result (possibly empty) in the variable, and than inspect the it. If it is not empty, you have the desired result; otherwise default it.

Comment: Where am I running `sed` twice?  If I'm understanding yours, it's matching the `${sfile}_finddir` part and then if it matches, extracts the part of the line between `"`.  In my example, it just looks for the whole line including the `${sfile}_finddir` and extracts the same portion.   I'm not seeing where the way I was doing it runs `sed` twice?

Comment: I made those changes, I used the `sed` syntax you gave, in case there is a good reason not to use mine (though both work) and I also moved some of the var and d_var around to make it work better, the script does work as I expect, and I have that in its entirety here, if you wanted to see what exactly I was doing: http://pastebin.com/ffr8AJdG

Comment: ignoring the commented out section, I believe I have it finalized now: http://pastebin.com/fpHZv1Aa